# Stored procedure taking too much execution time. Is there any way to optimize the following sql script

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to drive marks obtained, total marks and average column from Marks Column which is of varchar type.

[image]

Stored procedure that I wrote is taking very much time in execution. As Table contains 346599 records. Stored procedure have 3 update quires init.

```
Declare @Max_ROWss int
Declare @j int
Declare @Marks_Obtained int
Declare @Total_Marks int
Declare @Marks nvarchar(50)
Declare @Average int

Set @MAx_ROWss = (Select Count([Row Number]) From [dbo].[Drv Tevta 3 Full] ) -- Max([Row Number]) will also work
Set @j = 1
while (@j<= @MAx_ROWss)
Begin
    set @Marks = (select [Marks] from [dbo].[Drv Tevta 3 Full] where [Row Number] = @j)

    Set @Total_Marks =cast((select SUBSTRING(@Marks, CHARINDEX('/', @Marks) + 1, 10)) as int)
    set @Marks_Obtained = CAST((Select SUBSTRING(@Marks,0,CHARINDEX('/',@Marks))) as int)

    Update [dbo].[Drv Tevta 3 Full] 
    set [Marked Obtained] = @Marks_Obtained
    where [Row Number] = @j

    Update [dbo].[Drv Tevta 3 Full] 
    set [Total Marks] = @Total_Marks
    where [Row Number] = @j

    set @Average = ((@Marks_Obtained*100)/@Total_Marks)
    Update [dbo].[Drv Tevta 3 Full] 
    set [Average] = @Average
    where [Row Number] = @j

    set @j = @j + 1
End
```

Is there a better way it can be done? or I i just have to wait !

Comment: One UPDATE instead of several.

Comment: a) please tell us that is test data and not real. b) you need to actually provide the DB schema, primary keys / indexes etc so that we know what the physical DB model is. The query plan would also be useful. As it stands, that code is written in a non-set based manner, so you should start by rethinking through how you solved this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `while` loop to do this

```
UPDATE f
SET    [Marked Obtained] = Cast((SELECT Substring(Marks, Charindex('/', Marks) + 1, 10)) AS INT),
       [Total Marks] = Cast((SELECT Substring(Marks, 0, Charindex('/', Marks))) AS INT),
       [Average] = ( Cast((SELECT Substring(Marks, Charindex('/', Marks) + 1, 10)) AS INT) * 100.0 ) / Cast((SELECT Substring(Marks, 0, Charindex('/', Marks))) AS INT)
FROM   [dbo].[Drv Tevta 3 Full] f 
--Where [Row Number]>= 1
```